# Compare Date in Access Database Query in Visual C#

Tags: c#, sql, database, ms-access, oledb

I'm trying to compare a stored date (Datetime) to the current system date. I'm using the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM   Table
WHERE  (StoredDate > Date())
```

and it gives me the correct result. But it also states there is an

```
SQL syntax error in the WHERE-Clause near ")". Analyzing of query string not possible.
```

The time format I set up in Access is 'General Date'. It works fine if I compare the date with an integer.

Can anyone see the problem?

Cheers

Kruspe

Comment: Is this your real query? `Table` is an SQL reserved word. Is this an MS Access database? Tag your question with `MS-Access`. How are you querying this database? Through C#? Show us your C# code. What is the “it” that gives you a “correct result” yet also gives you an SQL syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you don't supply a time along with a date, SQL Server automatically assumes midnight (there are no independant Date and Time datatypes up to SQL Server 2000, there are supossed to be ones in SQL Server 2005). Look up the DATETIME datatype in SQL Server Books Online.

If you want all records greater than 1/1/2005, try:

```
Select *
FROM tablename
WHERE datefield >= '1/1/2005 23:59:59.000'
```

or '1/1/2005 23:59:59.999' or whatever works for you.

(do a Select getdate() to see the current time in this format).

Also, do a search on this site for DATETIME. I believe there are several articles on the subject.

Comment: Thank you. I had to use the NOW() function instead.